# Есть таблица в sqlite3 с IF NOT EXISTS. Если я решу добавить больше полей в созданную уже таблицу, то создастся новая?

Tags: python, sqlite

**Есть таблица в sqlite3 с IF NOT EXISTS. Если я решу добавить больше полей в созданную уже таблицу, то создастся новая? Или же существование таблицы определяется по ее названию?**

Вот создается таблица:

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nickname TEXT, currency INT);""")
```

Я, к примеру, хочу добавить новое поле - password. В коде я вписываю его.

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nickname TEXT, currency INT, password TEXT);""")
```

При запуске этого кода просто добавятся новые поля или же создастся новый столбец из-за условия CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS? Возможно соблюдение условия проверяется по названию, но не могу быть уверен в этом. *Заранее спасибо!*

Код до:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('BotBase.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
print('Connected')

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nickname TEXT, currency INT);""")
```

Код, который я хочу запустить:

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('BotBase.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
print('Connected')

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nickname TEXT, currency INT, BTC INTEGER);""")
```

Comment: *Есть таблица в sqlite3 с IF NOT EXISTS* Переведите эту фразу в понятную форму. Лучше - выложите код (полностью), о котором идёт речь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, новая таблица не создастся. Проверка IF NOT EXISTS ищет и сравнивает название таблицы, а не его содержимое (столбцы). Поэтому после такого изменения вы лишь добавите еще один столбец.